# How to choose to open with Software Center application from the browser?

Tags: software-center, browser

I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04. I wanted to install fonts for the Indian languages and searching in Google led me to [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ttf-indic-fonts/) site.

[image]

When I clicked on the *available on the Software Centre* button, the *Launch Application* window opens. I clicked the *Choose* button to choose the Software Centre application. But I do not know the location to choose from i.e., where the Software Centre application resides on my PC. How do I find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the location of Ubuntu Software Center:

```
/usr/bin/software-center
```

(I've got it very quickly using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/347522/147044)).

[image: software-center]

[image: open]

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way as you can simply use the **Ubuntu Software Center** download with a search by hitting the <kbd>Super</kbd> key. I did a simple search and it is already visible there to install. Below is how in a simple way.

Copied the font you were searching for...

[image]

And opened the **Ubuntu Software Center** by hitting the <kbd>Super</kbd> key

[image]

Paste it on the search & it appeared to install.

[image]