# How do I start a Skype call from terminal?

Tags: command-line, skype, voip

is there a way to start a Skype call from the terminal?

I have found skype4py, but it doesn't work on ubuntu 12.04. Is there a solution without downgrading?

Comment: Maybe this post can give you an answer: [Open the same application from terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/347506/open-the-same-application-from-terminal/347522#347522)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes.
Once you have logged into skype and skype is running in background open a terminal window.

`skype --help`   gives you a list of options

```
$ skype --help
Skype 4.2.0.11

Usage: skype [options]
Options:
  --dbpath=<path>       Specify an alternative path to store Skype data files.
                        Default: ~/.Skype
  --resources=<path>    Specify a path where Skype can find its resource files.
                        Default: /usr/share/skype
  --secondary           Start a secondary instance of Skype.
  --disable-api         Disable Skype Public API.
  --callto <nick>
  skype:<nick>?<action>
                        These commands allow Skype links handling.
  --pipelogin           Command line login. "echo username password | skype --pipelogin"
  --version             Display version information and exit.
```

so `skype --callto <nickname>` allows to call some one who is currently on line
There is no obvious command line indication of whether there is a successful connection or not