# How to easily remove installed software?

Tags: package-management, uninstall, purge

I would like to know if there is an easy way to remove any installed software. I do know that `sudo apt-get remove <package-name>` command, but what happens when you don't know the package name. Let's say you install form a `.deb` file and you don't know what the package name is? It would be great if there was an universal un-installer, like the one in the Ubuntu Software Center, but for all packages.

Comment: Can you give an example of how or why this would happen:  _Lets say you install form a .deb file and you don’t know what the package name is?_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be useful for you.

[Uninstall Softwares using Aptitude](http://www.tricksfind.in/2010/10/ubuntuinstall-remove-download-by.html)

Comment: Again thank you for the help, you both will have made this much easier.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. If you know the application package name

From terminal, use one of the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove package_name
```

> **remove** is identical to install except that packages are removed instead of installed. Note that removing a package leaves its configuration files on the system. If a plus sign is appended to the package name (with no intervening space), the identified package will be installed instead of removed.
>
> <sup>Source: [`man apt-get`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)</sup>

```
apt-get purge package_name
```

> **purge** is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged (any configuration files are deleted too).
>
> <sup>Source: [`man apt-get`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)</sup>

You can also use:

- [`aptitude`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/aptitude) with the same arguments as of `apt-get`.
- Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: USC - remove app]

#### 2. If you know how to open the respective application from GUI

- Find application package name using this method:

  - [How can we get the command line of a running application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347506/open-the-same-application-from-terminal/347522#347522)
- Go to the step 1.

#### 3. If you forgot the application/package name and you don't know where to find it

**Ubuntu Software Center** is very useful in this sense. It knows about any application installed on your system: provided by Ubuntu, from Canonical partners, from purchase, from PPAs, from `.deb` files, etc. To find them:

- Click **Installed** tab and search there your application:

[image: USC - remove app]

- Click **History** tab, then **Installations** and search there your application/package:

[image: USC- history]

Answer (score 0):

There is aptitude, it is console based, but it gives you a complete list of the installed software and once you know the keyboard commands, it's fairly easy to navigate.

Otherwise, the following gives you a list of your package:

```
dpkg --list
```

But be careful, make sure to use apt-get to do removes/installs unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Ok thank you. I think that this will help my very much.