# How to know some app's console command in unity dash?

Tags: unity

Is it possible to see some app's console command from unity dash menu?

For example, I open the Dash via the windows key, type in some app name, it appears in the list below, and I do "something" to see how to start it from the command line.

I am asking this because I came across multiple 3rd party apps whose console command has nothing with the app name, and I was unable to figure out how to open such apps from the console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open the same application from terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/347506/open-the-same-application-from-terminal)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu The OP want to know how to extract the command from an icon in the Unity dash, not an already running instance (subtle differences).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I installed this app but this is not for my case (thou the script got upvote). What about when the app is not running?

Answer (score 3):

1. Navigate to this path in a file manager: `/usr/share/applications`

   For example, with Nautilus you would run (in a terminal)

   ```
   nautilus /usr/share/applications
   ```

   Note: some user created application launchers may reside in `~/.local/share/applications`
   Be sure to check there too, if you've created a custom `.desktop` file.
2. Locate your program by name (using search if required).
3. Right click the file for your program.
4. Select 'Properties'.
5. There should be a 'Command' field which shows the command to be executed. If the program has arguments such as `%U`, those are file arguments passed when that program is used to open a file.

Comment: More issues I have with apps located in /opt or other non-usual directories

Comment: @ubu If the app is installed to opt, then it will not have an icon unless you set it yourself.

Comment: @ubuntico See my edit. You should check `.local/share/applications` too.