# How do I find what command created an existing window?

Tags: window, command-line

In the system monitor application (`gnome-system-monitor`), there is a column titled "Command Line" that gives the command (complete with arguments) that was used to create that window.

Is there a command that allows you to select a window via clicking (like `xkill`), then returns the command called for that window?