# Command to run GUI Frontend for apt-get update

Tags: command-line, bash, gui, scripts

I want know, if there is any command to run apt-get update in GUI like in the picture following:

[image: GUI frontend of apt-get update]

All i want to do is to write a script which will update the software sources through this gui manager. So that i can make it more user friendly. I need the command to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do `apt-get update` from the command line of the update manager.

To run the command, use

```
update-manager
```

`man update-manaer` gives:

```
     --data-dir=DATA_DIR
          Directory that contains the data files

   -c, --check-dist-upgrades
          Check if a new distribution release is available

   -d, --devel-release
          Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible

   -p, --proposed
          Upgrade  using  the  latest  proposed  version  of  the  release
          upgrader

   --no-focus-on-map
          Do not focus on map when starting

   --dist-upgrade
          Try to run a dist-upgrade
```

so you can move over by running

```
update-manager --dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Isn't the OP asking for the GUI equivalent of update, not dist-upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell you exactly, as I'm not using a Ubuntu system at the moment, but I can tell you how to find the command.

1. Open a terminal and run this command ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/405041/176889)):

   ```
   xprop | awk '($1=="_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL)") {print $3}' | xargs ps h -o cmd
   ```
2. Click on a running instance of the GUI.
3. The command used to run it should then be printed in the terminal. You may have to adapt it slightly for use in a Bash script, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I learnt that the window is not a programm. sub programm of synaptic/software updator. So need to find if some complete software like what i want exists.

Answer (score 2):

On ubuntu you can run this as follows:

```
sudo /usr/bin/update-manager
```

If this doesn't work, find the actual command by following what Pavak Paul said:

```
 xprop | awk '($1=="_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL)") {print $3}' | xargs ps h -o cmd
```

Then click on running instance of update manager.